# On a problem of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem goes as follows:

For given continuous $A:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with all the real part of its eigenvalues is positive, then show there must exist some continuous $B:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$(B(t)+I)(B(t)-2I)=A(t)$$

I suppose the continuous here means the continuity derived from canonical Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}\simeq\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$, but that's not quite the first problem we should solve. I get totally no idea of how to do it. It seems unrealistic to expect that $B(\cdot)$ can be defined pointwise since there is no any condition on the diagolizability of $A$, and since all it asks is about existence theory, explicit construction may be out of question for the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this boils down to careful analysis of $(z+1)(z-2) = (z-1/2)^2 - 9/4$.

Assuming you know that
$$ z \mapsto z^2 : \{ z : \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 \} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$$
is a complex diffeomorphism, it is easy to deduce that
$$ z \mapsto (z+1)(z-2) : \{z : \operatorname{Re}(z) > 1/2\} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,-9/4]$$
is a complex diffeomorphism. Now make use of holomorphic functional calculus. Note that:
$$ \{ z  : \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0\} \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,-9/4].$$

Comment: It's a great idea to use functional calculus to define $B(t)$, but how can show thus defined $B(\cdot)$ is continuous?

Comment: I got the idea of proving continuity since its purely algebraic operation in finite-dimensional case and I nearly forgot this context...